# Intel Wifi 3160

Tags: wireless, drivers

What a weekend, first I installed Ubuntu, I know not to a big feat, but the last laptop I installed it on only had 1 partition and the new one had 4. What a pain in the rump. Now to the problem, the Wifi that is installed in the laptop is a Intel 3160 and it connects but it is only getting 1mb speed on a 2.4GHz N connection. What do I need to do to get a faster speed.

Comment: Start here http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: Try disabling IPv6 and possibly power management as shown [here](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/). Typically helps. Also, disable 802.11n.

Comment: Sorry Serg and mikewhatever for not Thank You also. I am new to this and did not realize that had also answered my question.

Comment: @Scott  No problem ! We're glad your issue has been solved and we've been able to contribute to the solution somehow. Enjoy the better internets  ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes little effort to get WiFI running back normally in Ubuntu for some laptops. I had the same issue and did many things,

```
1.disable power management
2.turn off 802.11
3.disable ipv6
```

The link given in your comments should solve your issue. Generally Ubuntu has built in drivers for most of the hardware. But you can change the default driver

Try changing it in Settings->software and updates-> Additional Drivers

It will fetch proprietary drivers for your WiFi. Select it and check if it works

Comment: It is nice to see people willing to help so fast.  Thank you Trinadh.  So I followed the link and did the echo "options........ and disable IPv6 restarted the laptop and now I am getting 64Mb. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @scott welcome, glad that you solved your issue