# Terribly slow WiFi connection; was perfectly fine on Win 8.1

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I'm having some trouble with my WiFi connection for some odd reason. This is my second time installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, which the first time I remember having the same problem, but I managed to fix it somehow. Aside from that, I connect to the WiFi perfectly fine, however my download speed is absolutely horrendous. I used to get anywhere from 500kb/s - 1.9mb/s on Windows 8.1 and my first installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but now it's ranging from a minimum of either nothing to a max 200kb/s, which is absolutely frustrating as you could imagine. I've tried a number of methods to try to fix it, but not one of them helped the issue at all. If I need to list my specs and whatnot, please tell me the command(s) to use in terminal to get them, and I will gladly post them. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the general fixes like disabling ipV6, 8011n and power management. ?

If not read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642114/intel-wifi-3160/642135#642135)

Unfortunately WiFi issue is most commonly encountered in Ubuntu. But there are guidelines to fix it. And you should find them in the above link